Why does the state of the modified stack pointer of my test program differ from the behavior in Linux in posix uefi?
I made a small test program to demonstrate:
#ifdef UEFI
#include "uefi/uefi.h"
#else
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#endif

register void* rsp __asm__("rsp");

#define setsp(sp) __asm__("mov %0, %%rsp\n" \
: \
: "r" (sp))

#define getsp(sp) __asm__("mov %%rsp, %0\n" \
: "=r" (sp)\
: )

char* sp;
char* sp2;
char* sp3;
char* sp4;

int setstack(int a)
{
    char* oldsp;
    etsp(oldsp);
    char* stack = malloc(2000);
    memcpy(stack + 1000, oldsp, 64);
    sp2 = stack + 1000;
    setsp(sp2);
    getsp(sp3);

    printf("rsp in function %p\n", sp3);
    printf("register rsp in function %p\n", rsp);
    return 0;
} 

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    getsp(sp);
    printf("rsp before function %p\n", sp);
    printf("register rsp before function %p\n", rsp);
    setstack(5);
    getsp(sp4);
    printf("rsp after function %p\n", sp4);
    printf("register rsp after function %p\n", rsp);

    while(1);

    return 0;
}

On Linux I compile it like this:
cc -fomit-frame-pointer test.c -o test

On Linux the output is:
rsp before function 0x7fff1f989a70
register rsp before function 0x7fff1f989a70
rsp in function 0x565084e6ba98
register rsp in function 0x565084e6ba98
rsp after function 0x565084e6bac8
register rsp after function 0x565084e6bac8

I see that the stack is changed in the function, and after returning from it it remains changed with a small change on ret. This is as I expect
In posix-uefi I compile it like this:
clang -Wall -Wextra --ansi -O2 -DUEFI=1 -DELF64 -Wno-unused-parameter -fomit-frame-pointer -I./include -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -ffreestanding -fno-stack-protector -fno-stack-check -I. -I./uefi -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/efi -I/usr/include/efi/protocol -I/usr/include/efi/x86_64 -D__x86_64__ -DHAVE_USE_MS_ABI -mno-red-zone --target=x86_64-pc-win32-coff -Wno-builtin-requires-header -Wno-in compatible-library-redeclaration -Wno-long-long -c test.c -o test.o
lld -flavor link -subsystem:efi_application -nodefaultlib -dll -entry:uefi_init uefi/*.o test.o -out:testsp.efi

And I run it in qemu (qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 2G -hda hda -bios /usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd -net none):
rsp before function 000000007fefa3a0
register rsp before function 000000007fefa3a0
rsp in function 000000007fefa3a0
register rsp in function 000000007df6b480
rsp after function 000000007fefa3a0
register rsp after function 000000007df6b480

I see that the "getsp" macro does not work correctly, and judging by the register variable, the value of the stack pointer in the function is equal to the value after it, as if there was no ret (these values ​​are slightly different when running on Linux). Can you explain these two points to me? Thank you.
